# How to make this type of image popping out of box using XHTML css

Tags: css, xhtml

How to make this type of image popping out of box using XHTML css. without using whole box along with image as a background

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/330963/1104592352-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/330963/1104592352-My-Desktop.png)

Only globe image will be image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The globe needs to be a transparent png, and then style the box ignoring the image, padding and a border to get the desired look. Then, whack position: relative on the box, and position: absolute on the image inside it. Then use top: Xpx; left: Xpx; to position the image as you like.

Edit: I've taken the code from the siulamvictor below, and edited it so it'll work for you.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
    border: #000 1px solid;
    background: #d5d5d5;
    padding: 20px;
}

.box img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
  Text here.
  <img src="image.png" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Change the top and right properties to positon the image as you need it.

Comment: @thebluefox - thanks it's wotking but a problem here if text is long then it goes behind the image

Comment: Put the text into a p tag, then give the p tag a width and display block, it'll wrap down onto multiple lines then. Alternatively you'll have to make the box wider.

Bare in mind that when the number of lines of text increases, your image will move depending on which sides you've positioned it from.

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: #d5d5d5;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2; 
    right: 20px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
Text here.
<img src="image.png" class="image" />
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i can't give position: absolute; to box

Comment: You need the position absolute on the image, and position relative on the box, you have them the wrong way round. Also, use padding to gain a height, instead of the height property.

Comment: ooo yes.... sorry for the mistake. this should be something similar to what you want, metal-gear-solid.  :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="globe-box">Some text<div class="globe"></div></div>

.globe-box {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 110px; /* width of globe + some padding */
  margin-bottom: 20px; /* how much globe should stick out of the bottom */
}

.globe-box .globe {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; /* size of globe */
  background-image: url(globe.png);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px; /* same as margin-bottom above only negative */
  right: 10px;
}
```